# Can anyone give me an idea for redirecting session time out to the login screen in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

In mobile device, when we clicked on home button it is going to Applifecyclestate-pausestate and after session time out it is navigating to login screen. But when i locked the mobile screen session time out is not working can u please help me in this issue .
thank you

Comment: A current limitation in Flutter is that the code only runs when the app is in the foreground. There is a [plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager) for Android to use the `AlarmManager` which might help.